# How to add click event for link type QuickViewGroupElement？

Tags: sapui5, popover

I have a QuickView popover like this:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition id="table_popover">
  <QuickView id="popover_quickView">
    <QuickViewPage id="popover_quickViewPage">
      <QuickViewGroup id="popover_quickViewGroup">
        <QuickViewGroupElement
          id="nav_link"
          type="link"
          value="navTo somePage" />
      </QuickViewGroup>
    </QuickViewPage>
  </QuickView>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

There is only `target` property for `QuickViewGroupElement`, no press/click event. I want to use `CrossApplicationNavigation` service in click event.

I tried to use `attachBrowserEvent`:

```
var oLink = sap.ui.core.Fragment.byId("AssignedTablePopover", "nav_link");

oLink.attachBrowserEvent("click", function() {
  console.log("click");
});
```

But found that `QuickViewGroupElement` did not extends `sap.ui.core.Control`, so do not borrow `attachBrowserEvent`.

So is my only option is to use `addEventListener` in vanilla js or `.click()` in jQuery? is there any more UI5 way?

---

Event the jQuery work around did not work, `QuickViewGroupElement` id in UI5 and DOM is not the same, just as in this [Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Rm4NYQld3GM50VjF?p=preview):

```
var oView = this.getView();
var oLink = oView.byId("nav_link");
var sId = oLink.getId(); // "idFirstPage1--nav_link"

// get nothing
var jQueryLink = $("#" + sId); 
var vanillaLink = document.getElementById("document.getElementById("idFirstPage1--nav_link")")

// returns link element, in real application, generated id might be __linkXXX
var realjQueryLink = $("__link0");
var realvanillaLink = document.getElementById("__link0");
```

The unique IDs of `QuickView` is very strange, I created an issue for UI5 in github : [OPENUI5 issues](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2136)

UI:

[image]

Comment: You can try [sap.m.Popover](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.Popover), where you can use any controls.

Comment: I've used `ResponsivePopover` before, but UX prefers `QuickView`. I've also tried to mimic `QuickView` using `ResponsivePopover` + `Page` + `SimpleForm`, but `SimpleForm` did not shows in `Page`, that's another question.

Comment: If possible kindly share the screenshot of the UI

Comment: Updated @inizio

Comment: Kindly share me the UI which you are trying to achieve it.

Comment: Already updated. I am trying to achieve:  click `nav_link`, fire click event, call `CrossApplicationNavigation` service to navigate to another flp page.

Comment: Check [Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/luS9W6?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a complicate thing to do. here is what you can try

I have attach the `afterOpen` event to a function `quickViewOpen`
and then I query for pages and group elements that have link type.
Next, I use jquery to look for the link to attach click event.

[Working example - jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nuroqew/edit?html,output)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MVC</title>
    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" type="text/javascript"
            src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.ui.table"
            data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex">
    </script>

    <script id="oView" type="sapui5/xmlview">
    <mvc:View height="100%" controllerName="myView.Template"
      xmlns="sap.m" 
      xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
      xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
    <Button text="Click" press="openQuickView"></Button>
    <QuickView id="popover_quickView" afterOpen="quickViewOpen">
      <QuickViewPage id="popover_quickViewPage">
        <QuickViewGroup id="popover_quickViewGroup">
          <QuickViewGroupElement
            id="nav_link"
            type="link"
            value="navTo somePage" />
          <QuickViewGroupElement
            id="nav_link2"
            type="link"
            value="navTo otherPage" />
      </QuickViewGroup>
      </QuickViewPage>
    </QuickView>
  </mvc:View>
    </script>
    <script>
      sap.ui.define([
        'jquery.sap.global',
        'sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller',
        'sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel'
      ], function(jQuery, Controller, JSONModel) {
        "use strict";

        var oController = Controller.extend("myView.Template", {
          openQuickView: function(oEvent) {
            var quickview = this.getView().byId("popover_quickView");
            quickview.openBy(oEvent.getSource());
          },
          quickViewOpen: function() {
            var fn = this.quickViewLinkClick; // event handle
            var oQuickView = this.getView().byId("popover_quickView");

            // get the link elements so that we can associate the values with the link click
            var linkElements = oQuickView.getPages()[0].getGroups()[0].getElements().filter(function(e) {
              return e.getType() === 'link';
            });

            // use jquery to look for the links and attach on click event
            this.getView().byId("popover_quickView").$().find("a.sapMLnk").each(function(i, e) {
              var elm = linkElements[i];
              $(e).click(function() {
                fn(elm);
              });
            });
          },
          quickViewLinkClick: function(elm) {
            console.log(elm.getValue());
          }
        });

        return oController;
      });

      var oView = sap.ui.xmlview({
        viewContent: jQuery('#oView').html()
      });

      oView.placeAt('content');
    </script>
  </head>

  <body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
    <div id="content"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Work around 1 @inizio:

Mimic QuickView using Popover + Form + Link

### Work around 2 @D. Seah:

```
var oQuickView = sap.ui.core.Fragment.byId("AssignedTablePopover", "common_quickView");
// unique id workaround
var oNavLink = jQuery.sap.byId(oQuickView.getId() + "-quickView-popover").find('a')[0];

jQuery.sap.byId(oNavLink.getAttribute('id')).click(function(e) {

});
```

UI team has approved this as a [feature request](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2136).

---

> I also found `QuickViewGroupElement` did not support `enabled`. So `Link` is a better choice.

### Work around 3

ResponsivePopover + QuickViewPage + Link

```
<ResponsivePopover
  showHeader="true"
  title="{entityPopoverModel>/name}"
  class="sapUiPopupWithPadding" initialFocus="pin">
  <content>
    <!-- do not add QuickView container-->
    <QuickViewPage header="{entityPopoverModel>/name}">
      <QuickViewGroup>
        <QuickViewGroupElement
          label="{i18n>ID}"
          value="{entityPopoverModel>/id}" />
        <QuickViewGroupElement
          label="{i18n>DESCRIPTION}"
          value="{= ${entityPopoverModel>/description} ? ${entityPopoverModel>/description} : '-'}" />
      </QuickViewGroup>
    </QuickViewPage>
    <Link text="hazard" press="onPress" enabled="false"/>
  </content>
</ResponsivePopover>
```

[image]